# Qual a melhor forma de fazer um mini-decodificador?

Tags: c#

Olá sou novato em programação e gostaria de saber a forma mais eficiente de fazer um "mini-decodificador". Tirei a ideia da minha professora que deu um dever que tínhamos que pegar o numero e transformar em letras para formar uma palavra rsrs (talvez um pouco de prezinho.. mas..)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;
        string[] stra;

        while (true)
        {
            str = Console.ReadLine();             
            stra = str.Split(' ');




            for(int i = 0; i < stra.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (stra[i])
                {

                    case "1":
                        Console.Write("z");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.Write("x");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.Write("v");
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        Console.Write("u");
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        Console.Write("t");
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        Console.Write("s");
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        Console.Write("r");
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        Console.Write("q");
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        Console.Write("p");
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        Console.Write("o");
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        Console.Write("n");
                        break;
                    case "12":
                        Console.Write("m");
                        break;
                    case "13":
                        Console.Write("l");
                        break;
                    case "14":
                        Console.Write("j");
                        break;
                    case "15":
                        Console.Write("i");
                        break;
                    case "16":
                        Console.Write("h");
                        break;
                    case "17":
                        Console.Write("g");
                        break;
                    case "18":
                        Console.Write("f");
                        break;
                    case "19":
                        Console.Write("e");
                        break;
                    case "20":
                        Console.Write("d");
                        break;
                    case "21":
                        Console.Write("c");
                        break;
                    case "22":
                        Console.Write("b");
                        break;
                    case "23":
                        Console.Write("a");
                        break;
                }

            }
            Console.Write("\n");

        }





    }
}
}
```

bom.. você escreve a sequencia de números (de 1 a 23) separado por espaço e ele transforma os números em letras, formando a palavra.. gostaria de saber se essa é a forma mais eficiente de fazer isso e se vocês tem alguns "exercícios" para eu treinar -q

PS: Sim, nao tem k,y,w propositalmente a pedido da professora.. rsrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem remover as letras k, y e w (que foram incorporadas ao alfabeto portugues na nova regra) (logo o 'a' vai valer `26` e assim por diante) voce pode pensar do seguinte modo.

Cada caracter ja e um numero, e esse numero e dado pela tabela ASCII. Esta e a parte das letras minusculas:

```
97    61    a
98    62    b
99    63    c
100   64    d
101   65    e
102   66    f
103   67    g
104   68    h
105   69    i
106   6A    j
107   6B    k
108   6C    l
109   6D    m
110   6E    n
111   6F    o
112   70    p
113   71    q
114   72    r
115   73    s
116   74    t
117   75    u
118   76    v
119   77    w
120   78    x
121   79    y
122   7A    z
```

O primeiro numero e o valor em decimal e o segundo em hexa. A letra vem em seguida (eu tirei a parte em octal sei la porque :P)

Agora, sabendo que 'a' vale 97, 'b' 98 e assim por diante e o seu "codigo", e mais facil converter: basta pegar o seu numero e somar alguma coisa. Se ele for um 1, preisamos somar `121`, que da 122, o codigo do 'z'.

Agora a gente so precisa de uma regra generica para dado um numero, obter o caracter dado por ele. Seja esse numero `x`. A regra e a seguinte:

`(27 - x) + 96`

Esse vai ser o numero do novo caracter. Por exemplo, para 'a', que vale 26, temos:

`(27 - 26) + 96 == 97`

e para 'z', que vale 1:

`(27 - 1) + 96 == 122`

E assim por diante. Depois de fazer essa conta, voce so precisa imprimir o caracter de novo. Logo,

```
Console.Write((char)x);
```

vai imprimir a letra correspondente.